# Passing User Id between controllers

Tags: codeigniter

Experts,

what's the recommended way to pass the user id (system internal id of the user used to query for the user info) between controllers in a codeigniter app?

I'm considering the following options:
1. Use the CI session id to query the database for the user id in every controller. That way I don't have to place the user id in the session which is a security concern. But this option means an extra db query in every controller
2. Store the user id directly in the session so I have it readily available to query for user info.

What do you think?

Comment: I did in the first way i will take username when user login. I will use that in a query and then i will save that data in session array. I will use it in every controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of MVC you're not normally supposed to talk directly between two controllers.  However in this case I would use the session.  As far as security goes there are plenty of extensions to codeigniter dealing with authentication such as [TankAuth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) and [WolfAuth](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/180732/) including many others that you might look into if that is your concern.  In this case however I'd say using the session to store a user id is perfectly fine as long as you're not storing sensitive data along with it.

You can read up on CodeIgniter sessions here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a great authentication library Ion Auth. Check it out

http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/